# How to update UIMenu and UIContextMenuConfiguration dynamically in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios15, uimenu

I am having a `UIAction` called "Add to Favourites" in `UIMenu` and `UIContextMenuConfiguration` for Cells of a `UITableView`. I want to change the menu the next time it is shown as "Remove from Favourites". But, I learnt that `UIMenu` is immutable.

How can I achieve my goal to update the menu dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc extension UIMenu {
    
    /// Recalculates menu on every appearance (e.g. when assigning to UIButtons as primary action)
    static func lazyMenu(builder: @escaping () -> UIMenu) -> UIMenu {
        return UIMenu(children: [
                // rebuild menu every time menu is accessed
                UIDeferredMenuElement.uncached { completion in
                    let menu = builder()
                    completion([menu])
                }
            ])
    }
}
```

Make sure that returned menu from your builder block includes .displayInline: e.g.

```
UIMenu(options: .displayInline, children: myMenuItems)
```